# use spring boot data redis Connect to the redis cluster problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I used spring boot data redis to connect to the redis cluster, using version 2.1.3  The configuration is as follows:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RedisConnectionFactory myLettuceConnectionFactory(GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig) {
    RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
    final List<String> nodeList = redisProperties.getCluster().getNodes();
    Set<RedisNode> nodes = new HashSet<RedisNode>();
    for (String ipPort : nodeList) {
        String[] ipAndPort = ipPort.split(":");
        nodes.add(new RedisNode(ipAndPort[0].trim(), Integer.valueOf(ipAndPort[1])));
    }
    redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisProperties.getPassword()));
    redisClusterConfiguration.setClusterNodes(nodes);
    redisClusterConfiguration.setMaxRedirects(redisProperties.getCluster().getMaxRedirects());
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
            .commandTimeout(redisProperties.getTimeout())
            .poolConfig(poolConfig)
            .build();

    RedisClusterClient clusterClient ;

    LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration,clientConfig);
    return factory;
}
```

However, during the operation, a WARN exception message will always be received as follows:

[image: error log]

Well, this seems to be a problem with lettuce, [How to map remote host & port to localhost using Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/941),but I don't know how to use it in spring boot data redis. Any solution is welcome, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer, so let's define a ClinentRourse like this:

```
 MappingSocketAddressResolver resolver = MappingSocketAddressResolver.create(DnsResolvers.UNRESOLVED ,
            hostAndPort -> {
                if(hostAndPort.getHostText().startsWith("172.31")){
                    return HostAndPort.of(ipStr, hostAndPort.getPort());
                }
                return hostAndPort;
            });

    ClientResources clientResources = ClientResources.builder()
            .socketAddressResolver(resolver)
            .build();
```

Then through LettuceClientConfiguration.clientResources method set in, the normal work of the lettuce.